# Permalinks don't update nor link properly

Tags: permalinks, events, plugin-wpml

I'm using Events Manager and WPML for my WordPress site. I have changed the permalinks formatting from the default `/?p=123` to use the article name. So, for example, let's say that I want to link from one event to another. I add the path to the event inside an anchor tag. I save the page and when it reloads then it still uses the original permalink formatting... So I thought it was just the events but no. If I want to link to anything on my site it still uses the default permalink formatting. All pages and posts also use the original formatting.

The second thing that is wrong is that with this in combination with the WPML translation plugin I have an error when linking events with two different languages on them. So let's say that event1 and event2 are both translated in English and in German. Now when I am on event1 on the English version of it and links to the German version of the event2 it still uses the English event2 translation.

So all the permalinks are broken in some way when they always use the original formatting. And when linking to another event with another language on it it still uses the original linking events language on it, despite I add the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

How are you linking to the other events?

Are you hard-coding the anchor links somewhere, like in your post content or custom fields? As in, are you typing out `<a href="example.com/?p=123">`? If so, you might have manually update all of the links you added to use the new permalinks.

After you updated the permalink settings to `%postname%`, are you seeing the correct slug on regular pages and posts? Or is it still showing the default `?p=123`?

For WP Events Manager, it looks like you might need to also add some custom code to your functions.php file to get the URL structure to work the way you want it to:

https://www.wp-eventmanager.com/documentation/changing-event-slugpermalink/

Comment: Great gona try it out on monday!